# How to extract tr tag?

Tags: c#, html, parsing

How to extract the inner `<tr>` from the first `<tr bgcolor ..>` ?

```
<tr bgcolor="#FFF000">
  <div>
    <table>
         <tbody>
             <tr height="10">
             ...
<tr bgcolor="#FFF000">
  <div>
    <table>
         <tbody>
             <tr height="10">
             ...
...
```

What i've tried so far but it returns all inner `<tr>`:

```
      nodelist = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where
            (x => (x.Name == "tr" && x.Attributes["height"] != null && x.Attributes["height"].Value.Contains("10"))).ToList();
```

Comment: Are you using XDocument or HtmlAgilityPack to parse the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery)(Which is a jQuery port for C#). It uses CSS selectors so you could do something like this :

```
var innerTr = dom.Select("tr[bgcolor='#FFF000'] tr").First();
```

Answer (score 0):

`tr` cannot be descendant of another `tr`. I assume that nested tag is `td`:

```
nodelist = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
    .First(x => x.Name == "tr" && x.Attributes.Contains("bgcolor"))
    .Where(x => x.Descendants().Any(y => y.Attributes["height"] != null && x.Attributes["height"].Value.Contains("10")))
    .Select(x => x.Descendants())
    .ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath for this

```
var tr = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tr[@bgcolor='#FFF000']//tr[@height='10']");
```